# how disable automatic logging with facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

I am trying to integrate  login with faceBook,I follow  facebook tutorial 
from facebook developer

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

and login is successful,but when to try login again it already login 
I am try to disable automatic login by add

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
        android:value="false"/>
```

but nothing happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Log out user from facebook after some action use

```
if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null && AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    //there is an active user,just Log out the user 
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }
```

Comment: Levon Petrosyan
 i am using  loginButton.registerCallback  not LoginManager
can you  give me some details

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik it doesn't matter,you can check if there is active fb user by `Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null && AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null` and if this is true there is an active user,just Log out the user `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` and clicking login button again will let you to Log in again.